# What button is this pilot pressing with his thumb?

Tags: flight-controls, pilots, airline-pilot

In [this video (marker 4:23)](http://youtu.be/ztqZvTfAMLI?t=4m23s), what button is the pilot thumbing on the yoke?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the elevator trim control to relieve control forces in pitch.  It does this by changing the neutral position of the elevators so that the pilot flying does not need to maintain a constant pressure on the yoke to maintain pitch.  On the 747 family, this is achieved by moving the stabiliser.

Although [this image](http://www.cockpitbuilders.com/community/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=633.0;attach=525;image) shows a home cockpit yoke, the representation of the controls is accurate:

[image: 747 yoke trim switches]

Comment: To be clear, in most large aircraft (maybe all?), the stabilizer is what is moved when trimming.

Comment: @Terry Thanks, good point.  I'll edit that in.